# Rewrite paths of opened files

Tags: files, path

How can I tell Emacs than whenever it tries to open file `/a/b/c/foo.txt`, it should instead open `/d/e/f/foo.txt`?

I have a few projects and libraries which are accessible via multiple paths on the filesystem. This is mostly done by symlinks, but not only - sometimes I use bind mounts (some software, e.g. git, treats symlinks differently), and sometimes the files will simply always be identical copies of some other files.

Although when manually opening files, I always open them at their canonical location, following error messages and using "go-to-definition" actions will often open files under aliased paths, and I will end up with multiple buffers pointing to the same file. As such, I'd like to define a rule set of how to rewrite paths of all files it attempts to open. What would be the way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Emacs file-name aliases. See the Emacs manual, node [File Aliases](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/File-Aliases.html). See, in particular, option **`directory-abbrev-alist`**.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know off-hand of a better way to do it, but you might use `defadvice` on the `find-file` function. Your advice could rewrite the file path as needed before passing it in to `find-file`.

Comment: (Oops. I accidentally edited this answer instead of mine. Rolled it back to what it was.)